# Using a .json Database I Created

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am looking to use a .json file as a database to pull data from. I want to convert each index of the json file into an array which can be used for a tableview and segue.

```
[
  {
    "email address": "test@gmail.org",
    "first name": "First",
    "last name": "Last"
  },
  {
    "email address": "test2@gmail.org",
    "first name": "First2",
    "last name": "Last2"
  }
]
```

From there, I want to be able to convert each index into:

```
NSArray*testArray = @[@"test@gmail.org",@"First",@"Last"];
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You have nicely structure data. Why do you want to remove the structure by putting the values into an array?

Comment: I does not appear that you have any index at all in your current JSON structure, so I am not clear what you mean when you say "I want to convert each index of the json file into an array". The only index implied in your data structure would be a numerical array index to each object once the JSON is deserialized.

Comment: I would just like to somehow take the data from the json file and use it in my table cells. I just don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: To do that you write software.  Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use NSJSONSerialization to put your JSON into a dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

When you have done that, you can access your data by key, which keeps your code much cleaner than using hard coded array indexes.